# Converting nominal attribute to numeric value using Weka

Tags: weka

Suppose nominal attribute is Outlook which contains three values Sunny ,   Overcast and Rainy. I want to convert this values of outlook attribute in  numeric form i.e. 1,2,3 (order can be change). I saw one filter  nominaltobinary in weka but this will create  three columns. I don't want to create separate column for each value. How I can do this using Weka.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: because some model will give error if input variable contains non-numeric values.

Comment: That is true but i think that applies for string attributes and not for nominal ones. I think nominal are converted to numbers internally. What model are you using?

Comment: but when I am loading this kind of data in Weka then some of the models will get disabled

Comment: What models are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In the ARFF, if you are using it, you can have a comment which specifies what the values of the "Outlook" attribute are.

For example, you ARFF can contain this comment at the top -

```
%% Numeric values for the "Outlook" Attribute
%%   Sunny = 1
%%   Overcast = 2
%%   Rainy = 3
%%   Windy = 4
```

Then you can define the attribute as -

```
@attribute Outlook {1,2,3,4}
```

I dont think there is a way to do this in the UI. But you can use a text editor to edit the ARFF itself.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use "RenameNominalValues" filter under unsupervised ---> attributes.

Then under "selectedAttribute" type the attribute and

under "valueReplacements" type as Sunny:1,Overcast:2,Rainy:3,Windy:4

[image]